# Transgress 5 mitzvos by not returning the siddur?

Tags: jewish-books, synagogue

I was told that if one does not replace the sefer one is using in the Beis Hamedrash, one can transgress several (5?) mitzvos from the Torah.

I can see that one would transgress “love your neighbour as yourself” - what are the others?

Comment: If someone else is looking for that sefer then you are wasting his time (causing him bitul Torah). A case could be made for gneivas da'as I guess. Then the person doesn't learn so you have placed a michshol. https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/puting-away-seforim-after-using-them

Comment: לא תרדה\תעבוד בו בפרך - causing another Jew to work needlessly.

Comment: If they insist how is it not retroactively theft of their property?

Comment: I think a siddur and a book is different Your title says siddur but the question about a book. Siddurim are plenty, and there's no need to search for one, but if one volume of Schottenstein is missing exactly what you're looking for, it's really bad

Comment: @AlBerko I dunno what your shul is like, but in mine, we have one or two shelves of several types of Siddurim each, rather than twenty of the same type. Very often enough people forget the same type of Siddur that if someone’s looking for that particular edition there won’t be any.

Comment: @DonielF Still you can potentially use others, while with books you can't use a different volume. We have hundreds of siddurim and most people don't care about editions so much.

Comment: @AlBerko Again, that’s just you. Some people might not be able to focus properly with the wrong siddur. The same argument could be made for other Sefarim - some people can only learn well with an Oz Vehadar Shas, but the only ones on the shelf are the older editions.